# Providing additional functionality to multiple classes

Tags: c#, class, selenium

Selenium has multiple classes providing mechanisms for certain browsers.

So there are the following drivers (I care about most): `FireFoxDriver`, `ChromeDriver`, `InternetExplorerDriver`,

All of these, inherit from `RemoteWebDriver`.

```
public class FireFoxDriver : RemoteWebDriver { ... }
public class ChromeDriver : RemoteWebDriver { ... }
public class InternetExplorerDriver : RemoteWebDriver { ... }
```

Now, I would like to provide additional functionality/helpers to each driver such as, for example, going to URL and executing the script:

```
public void Goto(string url)
{
    Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
    ExecuteScript("console.log('Using selenium');");
}
```

I want to have this functionality for every driver (either FireFox, Chrome and IE) so I could do:

```
var chrome = new ChromeDriver();
chrome.Goto("https://google.com/");
```

So yeah, what is the proper way to do that?

Basically, I could get it working with creating a `BaseRemoteWebDriver` class, put my functionality in there and then create a `BaseChromeDriver`, `BaseFireFoxDriver`, `BaseIEDriver` and inherit from `BaseRemoteWebDriver`.

This way, I could perhaps achieve what I want, however I would endup having three, basically empty classes that inherit from `BaseRemoteWebDriver`, containing only generated constructors.

Is this the only (valid) way to extend the classes in C#?

Comment: So you want an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) so you don't have to call `driver.Navigate().GoToUrl`?

Comment: Yep, so I could simply call `driver.Goto`, for example.

Comment: But how is that better than `driver.Navigate().GoToUrl`? Other than obfuscating what you are doing to anyone else looking at your code?

Comment: It's not the case of being better or shorter, it's the case of having additional functionality in one place I could modify in a second, whenever I navigate to a page. I mean, why would I want to repeat the same code multiple times... and in case of changes, dig into multiple files.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [`Extension Methods`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

Then you could write something like this:

```
public static class RemoteWebDriverExtensions
{
    public static void Goto(this RemoteWebDriver driver, string url)
    {
         driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
         driver.ExecuteScript("console.log('Using selenium');");
    }
}
```

And then call it like that:

```
RemoteWebDriver chromedriver = new ChromeDriver();
chromedriver.Goto("https://google.com");
```

Comment: @DavidG whops forgot the static in the function definition

Comment: Looks promising, I will give it a try!